# Hide webgrid column "Edit" link based on condition in MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a webgrid `MVC3` contains 4 columns Name, Address, age & Edit. I want to hide `Edit` link for row if age is greater than 55. Help me to do it.

Is there any event like `OnItemDataBound` event?

Thank you

Comment: Can you share some code on what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any event like OnItemDataBound event?

No, there is no such concept as events in ASP.NET MVC.

You could use a custom format column.

Model:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var persons = new[]
        {
            new PersonViewModel { Id = 1, Name = "u 1", Address = "a 1", Age = 54 },
            new PersonViewModel { Id = 2, Name = "u 2", Address = "a 2", Age = 55 },
            new PersonViewModel { Id = 3, Name = "u 3", Address = "a 3", Age = 56 },
        };
        return View(persons);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<PersonViewModel>
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}

@grid.GetHtml(
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("Name"),
        grid.Column("Address"),
        grid.Column("Age"),
        grid.Column(
            header: "Edit", 
            format: 
                @<text>
                @if (item.Age < 56) 
                { 
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = (int)item.Id }) 
                }
                </text>
        )
    )
)
```

Obviously the fact that you have *hidden* the link doesn't relieve you from the burden to perform the same check against the Age inside the `Edit` controller action given the person id. There's nothing preventing a user from entering the url of this Edit action directly in his browser address bar.