# Hide/Show Editable links in webGrid CSHTML code

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to Hide/Show the 'Edit' link in each row of a given Grid. Basically only few user roles have the access to Modify the information. I wrote a method ActionResult in controller class to check the user access and returning Boolean value. Based on True/False I need to Hide/Show the 'Edit' Links in a grid. The design code is written in MVC CSHTML. Please suggest how it can be achieved. I tried using JQuery but I can hide the Edit column only for the first row of the grid. Below is the code in CSHTML and Jquery.

CSHTML Code

```
    <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" style="width: 90%;"><tr>
<td>
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGridMedium",
headerStyle: "header",
alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
selectedRowStyle: "select",
columns: grid.Columns(
grid.Column("BeginDate", "Begin Date", style: "description"),
grid.Column("Status", "Status", style: "description"),  
grid.Column("", style: "description10", format: @<a class="edit-status" id="btnEditStatus" href="">Edit</a>)
))
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JQuery Code: The parameter data is boolean value I get it from Controller class.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
    checkAccess();     
    }    
        function checkAccess() {
            //     debugger;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Employee/CheckAccess',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {},
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == false) {
                        document.getElementById("btnEditStatus").style.visibility = "hidden";

                    }
                    else if (data = true) {
                        document.getElementById("btnEditStatus").style.visibility = "";

                    }
                },
                error: (function (result) {
                    alert("Failed access! Please contact administrator.");
                })
            })
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>       
function checkAccess() {
        // debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Application/CheckAccess',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == false) {
                $('.modaltable tr').each(function (i, row) {
                    $(this).find('.edit-status').hide();
                });
                                 }    
            else if (data = true) {    
                      // your code    
                                  }  
        },  
        error: (function (result) {
            alert("Please contact IT administrator for access.");
        })
    })
 }    
</script>
```

Comment: write each function and hide the column using  $(this).find('.edit-status').hide();

Comment: This worked perfect http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937450/hide-webgrid-column-edit-link-based-on-condition-in-mvc3